# runtime error when access pointer class member variable c++

Tags: c++, crash, polymorphism, runtime, member

I am having a problem accessing a member variable through a pointer. The pointer is the static list, which through polymorphism will point at inheriting classes.

Here is class A and its inheritors, as well as the ctors:

```
class A
{
    public:

        A();

        char letter;

};

class B: public A
{
    public:
        B();
};

A::A()
{
    letter = 'a';
}

B::B()
{
    letter = 'b';
}
```

class Display makes a static array of class A and sets values:

```
class Display
{
    public:

        Display();

        static A* aList;

        A a;
        B b;

};

A* Display::aList = nullptr;

Display::Display()
{

    aList = &b;

}
```

Class App uses the array to display the letter:

```
class App
{
    public:

        App()
        {
            std::cout << Display::aList->letter << endl;
        }

};
```

The main files runs App's ctor

```
main()
{
   App app;
}
```

The program crashes at runtime.

Why?

Comment: This is too much for code to go through to track down whatever problem you have. Consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _"It is a 3d vector that is properly initialized elsewhere in the code, so I know that it isn't an issue"_ Make _us_ know. Prove it. An MCVE isn't just something to "consider": we actually require it.

Comment: Completely re wrote the program as a MCVE that replicates the crash.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue with my original question was that the class member boolean I was trying to access through static object list was unpointed to.

runtime crash:

```
cout << A::staticList[5]->n << endl;
```

working way:

```
if( cout << A::staticList[5] != nullptr )
{
    cout << A::staticList[5]->n << endl;
}
```